# array returns length of 0 although it has values

Tags: javascript, async-await

so i am trying to push items to an array and it appears to be return a length of 0 although there are items in the array.

```
let calendarDates = []

async function getDates() {
    const response = await fetch('/calendars/fetch_dates')
    let res = await response.json()
    res.forEach(el => {
        calendarDates.push(el)
    })
}

getDates()
createCalendar(date, side)
.
.
.

function createCalendar(date, side) {
    console.log('createCalendar', calendarDates, "is array?", Array.isArray(calendarDates), 'length', calendarDates.length)
.
.
}
```

my console.log is printing calendarDates and length : 
[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4T4Z.png)

[console log for length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxnfd.png)

the console.log lives in a seperate function

so why is it returning 0 for the length? 
when trying to console log a forEach loop nothing returns either so i dont thing its the browser showing the wrong value for fun

Comment: where do you put your `console.log`?

Comment: @YongQuan updated my code snippet to show where the console log lives

Comment: getDates is an asynchronous function while createCalendar is a synchronous function. So createCalendar will be called first and will try to read the length of the array before the getDates function gets the async data.

Comment: I believe the inconsistency you are seeing is with the way `console.log()` works (at least in Chrome). `createCalendar()` is being called before `getDates` finishes but `console.log()` is delayed and uses a later value of `calendarDates`... I don't know if I'm explaining that right.. Like `console.log` computes the arguments but because calendarDates is an array it's passed by reference. So you can't trust that the value is the same in the log as when it was actually called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help

```js
async function Main() {
  let calendarDates = []
  calendarDates = await getDates();
  createCalendar(date, side)
}

async function getDates() {
  const response = await fetch('/calendars/fetch_dates')
  return await response.json();
}

function createCalendar(date, side) {
  console.log('createCalendar', calendarDates, "is array?", Array.isArray(calendarDates), 'length', calendarDates.length);
}


Main();
```

Comment: Try to explain to OP why your code works but not his.

Answer (score 1):

`getDates` is async function. So, if you call:

```
getDates()
createCalendar(date, side)
```

`createCalendar` may be called before getDates() do successful. Async, Promise are really important, you should practice and study carefully about them.

Comment: calendarDates = await getDates();
createCalendar(date, side);

we have used `await` for `getDates` function, so the `createCalendar` function will not be called unless we have `getDates` function fulfilled.

Comment: I agree with you code above :) I just talked with the questioner