# Javascript Wait for Promise to be resolved in a different function before continuing async function for animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a react-native app with an animation function and I'm trying to create an animation helper function that that waits for a value to be resolved on another screen before continuing execution and returning a value to the animation function.

The animation helper function depends on the result of a user buying or not buying a subscription on another screen, and I'm passing a promise to the second screen to be resolved with whether the user buys a subscription. After this promise is resolved I then want to continue the execution of my first animation helper function and return the value of whether the user bought a subscription to my first animation function.

Here is my animation function

```
Animated.timing(position, {
             toValue: {x: width, y: 0},
             duration: 300,
           }).start(async() => {
            const touchJustAdded = await animationHelper({props})
             this.setState({touchJustAdded: actionAllowed}) //This should update the state with the value returned from the animation helper before continuing animation. 
//touchJustAdded is used in another function to control the text shown in the animated view, so I need the value to be set here before continuing the animation.  I also don't want to continue the animation until the user returns from the BuySubscription screen. 
               Animated.timing(position, {
               toValue: {x: 0, y: 0},
               delay: 1200,
               duration: 300,
             })
           })
```

Here is my animation helper function

```
const AnimationHelper = async ({props}) => {
  //check if user has a subscription or other conditions are met, do stuff, then return true.   Otherwise, navigate to BuySubscription screen
  navigation.navigate('BuySubscription',{promiseCallback})
  //I want to pause execution here until the promiseCallback promise is resolved
  return subscriptionBought //I need to wait for the user to complete their action on the other screen and then somehow return the value to the animationHelper before returning here
}
```

Here is how I'm creating the promise:

```
promiseCallback = async (subscriptionBought) => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    resolve( subscriptionBought)
  })
}
```

This promise is resolved in the BuySubscription screen with this code when the user navigates away from that screen:

```
  this.props.navigation.state.params
    .promiseCallback(this.state.subscriptionBought)
```

I want to wait for the promise to be resolved before continuing the AnimationHelper.

Any help is appreciated! I've searched but I don't understand how to await the promiseCallback in the Animation function without calling it.

Comment: do you mean that you want to open another screen, and wait in this screen until user do for example payment or cancel it?

Comment: I want to wait for the user to complete the payment or cancel it on the other screen before continuing the first Animation function.  I edited my question as well to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without promise like this:

Screen1:

```
promiseCallback = (subscriptionBought) => {
  alert("Result: " + subscriptionBought)
  // continue your animation here
}

const Animation = async ({props}) => {
  //start animation
  navigation.navigate('BuySubscription', {promiseCallback: this.promiseCallback})

  return
}
```

Now in your `BuySubscription` screen call `promiseCallback` on `componentWillUnmount` events:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.props.navigation.state.params.promiseCallback(this.state.subscriptionBought);
}
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't quite work because I need to return the value of whether the user bought a subscription from my animation function. The animation function is actually called by another function that does the actual animation. Sorry for the naming confusion - I'll update my question with this requirement to return the value.  If there was a way to await the promiseCallback function being called in the AnimationHelper function then this could work, but I don't see a way to do that.

Comment: @theoryweary I think you want to wait inside AnimationHelper function, Right? If so, it's not possible and it's not good way to do.

Comment: @theoryweary You can not wait for user action finish inside function. You can define your `AnimationHelper` as a `state` and set your `subscriptionBought` to that state after user finished action

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const functionToAwait = async ({props}) => {
  let hold = await promiseCallback();
  if(hold){
  navigation.navigate('BuySubscription',hold)
  //I want to pause execution here until the promiseCallback promise is resolved
  return
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However this doesn't seem to work because let hold = await buySubscriptionCallback() immediately resolves the promise. Instead I want to wait until the promise is resolved on the other screen when the user buys a subscription or cancels before continuing the first Animation function.   I also need to pass in whether the user bought the subscription when resolving the callbackPromise.    I edited the function name in my question to make this more clear as well.    Thanks you!!

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to `await` in your promise `function`. And also have to await where you call the promise function.

`e.g.`

```js
promiseCallback = async (subscriptionBought) => {
  return await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    resolve( subscriptionBought)
  })
}
```

[Please see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877623/array-returns-length-of-0-although-it-has-values/54877735#54877735)

Comment: Hi, I tried adding this logic, but my AnimationHelper function still runs immediately so I cannot return whether the user bought a subscription in the AnimationHelper function with this. I just edited my question above to make it more clear.  I also looked at your other answer but I cannot create a Main function with my promiseCallback inside because I do not want to call the promiseCallback from the AnimationHelper method. I need the BuySubscription screen to call the promiseCallback.